# WorksheetFunction Sum of a range outputs 0

Tags: excel, vba

I do some calculations before displaying.

The "sum" function outputs 0 despite the values in the range.

```
sub CompileDashboard()
    For i = 3 To 100
        If Sheets(1).Cells(i, "A").Value = "Week 36" Then
            Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(i, "AN"), Cells(i, "BF")))
        End If
    Next
End sub
```

*Note: This is a simplification of the step that isn't working.*

Comment: try my answer below. You noticed you are overwriting your Result everytime ?  you are putting the Sum in `Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1)`, didn't you mean also to advance the row with the `For` loop, and the result should be:  `Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1)`

Comment: if you want to sum up everything in `Cells(1,1)` then `Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1) = Sheets(1).Evaluate("SUM(AN3:BF100*(A3:A100=""Week 36""))")` will do it in one line ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments this line:

`Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(i, "AN"), Cells(i, "BF")))`

Needs to be changed to

`Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(i, "AN"), Cells(i, "BF")))`

Just a variation on the theme. I really like this syntax, but you never see it.

```
Sub CompileDashboard()
    Dim i As Integer
    With Sheets(1)
        For i = 3 To 100
            With .Rows(i)
                If .Columns("A").Value = "Week 36" Then

                    Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1) = Application.Sum(.Columns("AN:BF"))

                End If
            End With
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Neat alternate of an [Intersect method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772.aspx).

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks.  I feel like it really cleans up the code.  I also like `Columns("A").Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlup)` but I don't use it because people aren't used to seeing it.

Comment: Well, the only stigma I see is that the benefits of wrapping parent worksheet reference in a With ... End With are lost when the With ... End With is within a For ... Next ; i.e. it is repeatedly re-referenced.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I reworked my answer it a little.  It looks like a pretty good pattern to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to **SUM** the row (from `Sheets(1)`) for all columns between "AN" and "BF, then modify your line :

```
Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(i, "AN"), Cells(i, "BF")))
```

to:

```
Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets(1).Range("AN" & i & ":BF" & i))
```

Comment: I believe Sheet2 is active and the OP is summing blank cells in Sheet2's `Range("AN" & i & ":BF" & i)` when they intend to sum the same range from Sheet1.

Comment: @Jeeped you might be right (or he is looking to sum from `Sheets(2)` , it is not clear), anyway modified the asnwer , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Always provide explicit [.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980.aspx) worksheet references for all [Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) and 
[Range.Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) objects. A [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) can easily accomplish this and not only cleans up your code but makes it run faster.

```
sub CompileDashboard()
    with Sheets(1)
        For i = 3 To 100
            If .Cells(i, "A").Value = "Week 36" Then
                 Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1) = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(i, "AN"), .Cells(i, "BF")))
            End If
        Next
    end with
End sub
```

The purpose of your loop is unclear. If there is only one row with "Week 36" then you should be exiting the For ... Next statement once it is found; in fact, a `Application.Match(...)` would find it instantly. If there are more than one row with "Week 36" then you shouldn't be overwriting the same cell on Sheet2.